# Big endian и Little endian для IPv4 и IPv6

Tags: c++, c, сеть, winsock2

Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю:

Big endian и Little endian - различаются между собой собственно просто порядком байт. Но, я вдруг запутался немного, а в каких именно байтах имеет значение этот порядок ?

Ну вот к примеру возьмем стандартную форму записи IPv4 уже в двоичном виде - он будет занимать 4 байта. В данном случае порядок байт будет применен именно в целом к этим 4 байтам?

Или же к 4ем октетам по отдельности ? Если так, то прямой и обратный порядок для IPv4 не имеет значения, так как каждый октет состоит ровно из одного байта. А вот в случае с IPv6 прямой и обратный порядок будет иметь значение - так как ipv6 состоит из 8 хекстетов по два байта каждый.

Я правильно понимаю ?

Answer (score 2):

Вы собственно сами ответили на свой вопрос - применять понятие big/little к одному байту нет смысла. Поэтому, оно примеряется к многобайтовым данным.

Так сложилось исторически, что по сети обычно бегают данные в big endian. И когда заполняются всякие tcp заголовки, то там порядок байт "прямой"

> Но, я вдруг запутался немного, а в каких именно байтах имеет значение этот порядок ?

это имеет отношения к "полям". Например, какой-то размер или порядковый номер.

> А вот в случае с IPv6 прямой и обратный порядок будет иметь значение - так как ipv6 состоит из 8 хекстетов по два байта каждый.

порядок в TCP/UDP заголовках будет "прямой".

А вот как это все будет сохранятся в пользовательском приложении - это другое дело. С большой вероятностью ipv6 будет сохранятся просто как последовательность байт, а вот ipv4 - как 4байтовый int/DWORD. И на x86 порядок в результате будет обратный.

Comment: "И на x86 порядок в результате будет обратный." - меня, как раз вот это и интересовало. То есть на машине с прямым порядком, значение байт int/DWORD будет в другом порядке, нежели в привычном x86 ? То есть, есть у меня IP условно: 186.78.195.67  - я просто взял создал int и напрямую в каждый байт int`а присвоил эти значения 186.78.195.67 - далее - этот int я передал в функцию Connect и Send. Но эти функции принимают данные в сетевом порядке, но я порядок не менял. Вот тут вопрос, я должен поменять порядок в int`е или нет ?

Comment: да, в большинстве случаев скорее всего нужно будет менять. и есть чудесные функции htos, htol которые Вам помогут

Comment: чуточку имя неверно указал. https://linux.die.net/man/3/htons  - эта функция конвертирует с хостового порядка в сетевой двухбайтовое (подходит для номера порта). htonl - с хостового в сетевой 4 байта (ipv4). Для big endian платформ это просто заглушки.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, вы совсем не правильно поняли. Big endian и Little endian (и совмещенные варианты) определяет, как та или иная аппаратная архитектура интерпретирует хранение разрядов в памяти для *арифметических* типов данных - integer, floating-point, fixed-point и т.п. Big endian - это когда подразумевается, что в байтах с меньшим адресом хранятся старшие разряды числа, а Little endian - что младшие. Адреса IP (4 или 6) не являются арифметическим типом данных. Big / Little endian никак на них не влияет, и они всегда должны интерпретироваться, как то описано в соответствующем RFC.

Comment: [When the bytes which make up such multi-byte numbers are ordered from most     significant byte to least significant byte, that is called "network byte order" or "big endian."](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-newman-network-byte-order-01#section-2) -- так вроде бы в rfc как раз и говорится, что BigEndian и NetworkOrder это одно и то же.

Comment: @avp Ну да, это синонимы.

Comment: @user7860670, "Адреса IP (4 или 6) не являются арифметическим типом данных. Big / Little endian никак на них не влияет" - но в Winsock сказано, что IP адреса должны передаваться по сети в Сетевом-Прямом порядке, а на x86 процессорах используется Обратный порядок. Не могу понять, что значит на них ни как не влияет ? Ведь преобразование нужно все таки делать ?

Comment: @Optimus1 Где это там сказано? Преобразовывать ничего не нужно. IP адреса обрабатываются одинаково вне зависимости от архитектуры.

Comment: @user7860670, вот тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/byte-ordering-2

Comment: @Optimus1 Там идет речь о параметрах, принимаемых функцией sockaddr. Там действительно адрес может задаваться как long и в этом случае следует быть осторожным, чтобы случайно его не перевернуть.

Comment: @user7860670, что Вы подразумеваете под словом "не перевернуть" ? Вот у меня есть IPv6 адрес в текстовом представлении, я с помощью inet_pton преобразовываю его в бинарное значение и помещаю в соответствующее поле структуры sockaddr. Но, inet_pton  не производит преобразование между порядками байт, то есть inet_pton выдаст мне не преобразованный результат в обратном привычном для x86 порядке, но в структуру sockaddr то нужно поместить IP в сетевом прямом порядке. То есть мне все таки нужно сделать преобразование ?

Comment: @Optimus1 Функция inet_pton не работает с арифметическими типами данных и  просто заполняет массив байт. Результат не зависит от того, является ли система Big endian и Little endian. И преобразования никакого делать не надо.

Comment: @user7860670, но массив байт заполняется в каком то определенном порядке же ? Как может результат не завесить от того, какой системы придерживается процессор ??

Comment: @Optimus1 Нет, байты везде хранятся одинаково, во всяком случае в С++ оговаривает вполне определенную модель памяти. Big endian и Little endian - это про то, как вычислительное устройство интерпретирует данные при выполнении арифметических операций.

Comment: @user7860670, ну так и я про тоже! Про то, как вычислительное устройство интерпретирует данные и если передать данные не в том порядке, вычислительное устройство будет их интерпретировать по своему и это вызовет "ошибку".

Comment: @user7860670, так как в этих комментариях писать не удобно, посмотрите пожалуйста мой овеет, там более удобно читать.

Comment: @Optimus1 Так с IP адресами незачем пытаться выполнять арифметические операции. Соответственно и разницы между Big endian и Little endian не проявится. Не знаю, что такое "овеет".

Comment: @user7860670 , я только что добавил ответ. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите:

```
temp_int1 = 0x2a03;  //10755

    std::cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << (unsigned int)(((unsigned char*)&temp_int1)[0]) << ":";
    std::cout << (unsigned int)(((unsigned char*)&temp_int1)[1]) << ":";
    std::cout << (unsigned int)(((unsigned char*)&temp_int1)[2]) << ":";
    std::cout << (unsigned int)(((unsigned char*)&temp_int1)[3]) << ":";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;


    std::cout << (unsigned int)(((unsigned short*)&temp_int1)[0]);
```

Вывод на консоль соответвенно будет:

> > 3:42:0:0:
>
> 10755:

То есть я взял и в int поместил число 10755 или 0x2a03 в hex`е.

А потом вывел значение каждого байта с 0 по 4. Видно, что значения байт вывелись сначала младший байт, потом старший. То есть в little endian.

Теперь!! Я беру текстовое представление ipv6:"2a03:2880:f10a:83:face:b00c:0:25de" c первым хекстетом 2a03 совпадающиv с тем, что я присваивал в int и вызываю функцию inet_pton:

```
char my_char_ipv6_ver1[] = "2a03:2880:f10a:83:face:b00c:0:25de";


    int family_protocol_ = 23;       //семейство протоколов.  2 - это для ipv4;  23 - это для ipv6;

    char my_transform_buffer_ipv6_ver1[16]; 


inet_pton(family_protocol_, my_char_ipv6_ver1, my_transform_buffer_ipv6_ver1);


//Сюда my_transform_buffer_ipv6_ver1 - функция inet_pton поместила преобразованный ipv6 из текстового представления в бинарный вид.

        std::cout << (unsigned int)(((unsigned char*)&my_transform_buffer_ipv6_ver1)[0]) << ":";
        std::cout << (unsigned int)(((unsigned char*)&my_transform_buffer_ipv6_ver1)[1]) << ":";
```

Вывод консоли:

> 42:3:

То есть выводим первые два байта первого хекстета 2a03 и видим, что значения поменялись!!! Теперь в первом байте указано значение 42, а во втором 3. То есть в соответствии с Big Endian.

Comment: `2a03` в строковой записи адреса `"2a03:2880:f10a:83:face:b00c:0:25de"` и в литерале `0x2a03` несут разный смыл... Адрес - это не целочисленный литерал, и в результате разбора получатся не арифметический тип, соответственно Big endian и Little endian роли не играет.

Comment: @user7860670, а в чем разница ?

Comment: Разница в том, что в литерале пишутся разряды числа, а в адресе - нет.

Comment: @ user7860670 , функция strtoull - без проблем принимает текст "2a03" и преобразовывает его в число в Little Endian, как в первом примере и ничто ей немешает.

Comment: Правильно, ведь `strtoull` служит для разбора строк, представляющих собой целые числа. По сути оно парсит аналогично тому, как компилятор разбирает числовой литерал.

Comment: @user7860670, а inet_pton для чего служит тогда ?

Comment: А `inet_pton` служит для разбора строковых представлений IP адресов.

Comment: @user7860670, а чем разница в интерпретации строкового числа "2a03" функцией strtoull и inet_pton? Очевидно, что они рассматривают эту строку, как реальное число 10755(dec) - но записывают ее в разной последовательности байт. Почему ?

Comment: *"Очевидно, что они рассматривают эту строку, как реальное число 10755(dec)"* - очевидно, что это не так. Собственно у вас основное затруднение и состоит в том, что вы почему-то упорно думаете, что IP адрес - это число. Причем опять же, Big endian и Little endian - это про арифметические операции, а тут на выходе получается массив из 16 байт. Можно представить, что внутри реализации `inet_pton` на каких-то этапах действительно используются целые числа, но она должна быть сделана так, что Endianess платформы на конечный результат не повлияет.

Comment: @user7860670, на основании чего, вы сделали вывод, что "очевидно это не так". Я написал на основании чего, но я не понимаю из чего вы делаете такой вывод. То есть вы просто противоречите и игнорируете факты.

Comment: *"Я написал на основании чего"* - скорее наоборот, вы решили, что 2a03 в начале адресе - это число, и решили сравнить его бинарное представление с бинарным представлением результата разбором литерала `0x2a03`. Хотя смыла в подобном сравнении нет.

Comment: @ user7860670, все верно, я решил, что хекстет - это число. Функция inet_pton думает не так же ? Если она думает не так же, то почему они преобразовывает его в число ?

Comment: `inet_pton` не преобразовывает его в число... Она преобразовывает адрес из строкового представления в массив байт.

Comment: @user7860670, а в байт помещает значение!! Или вы специально прикалываетесь или не специально запутываете. Я по другому уже не знаю что думать.

Comment: Первые два байта, которые вы выводите - это просто первые два байта из массива, а не две половины числа unsigned short.

Comment: @user7860670, эти первые два байта составляют число 2a03!

Comment: Нет, это два отдельных байта. Собственно весь адрес - это 16 отдельных байт. Если вы хотите интерпретировать первые два как половины одного числа - то это исключительно ваша собственная инициатива.

Comment: @user7860670, это не моя инициатива, это свойство описано в документации к функции: ""Указатель на буфер, в котором будет храниться числовое двоичное представление IP-адреса. IP-адрес возвращается в сетевом порядке байтов."". А значит вопрос заданный мной я понял правильно, хоть вы и написали, что я понял его не правильно.